# Построение столбчатой диаграммы по определенному столбцу

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, визуализация

У меня есть таблица, в которой указаны `product_name`, которое говорит за название продукта `product_id`, которое отвечает за id продукта.

Мне нужно построить диаграмму по кол-ву того или иного товара в дата сете. Но, чтобы по Х были отображены названия продуктов:

[image: таблица]

Получил информацию c помощью `value_counts`, а как дальше мне стоит визуализировать?

```
new_df["product_name"].value_counts()
```

Comment: На будущее: в вопросе нужно приводить воспроизводимые примеры исходных данных (в текстовом виде или ссылкой на файл), а не скриншоты.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну прямо так и рисуйте - [Series.plot.bar()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html) по умолчанию использует значения индекса в качестве подписей по оси `X`:

```
new_df["product_name"].value_counts().plot.bar(rot=45)
```

;)

Comment: Cпасибо, а скажите, если я хочу вывести, к примеру, 10 самых встречаемых признаков, что я должен сделать?

Comment: @ИльяПетров, выбрать десять первых строк после `.value_counts()` и потом тоже самое. Выбрать можно например так:  `.head(10)`

Comment: Понял, буду ставить "вверх" :)
Последнее подскажите, как здесь можно дать имя графику, когда использую вместо plot - plot(title = 'name'), у меня вместо диаграммы кривая линия начинает строиться.

Comment: @ИльяПетров, `.plot.bar(rot=45, title="name")` ?